# focusout element on trigger click event

Tags: jquery, events, triggers

I have come to a problem where a div on DOM needs to be triggered click when page loads,I have done this by -

```
<form>
...something which are not available on dom, 
   on trigger click this div loads
  ----
</form>
    <a class="use-ajax-comments">
    </a>

    $(".use-ajax-comments").trigger('click');
```

However after having auto triggered, the div is focused,which I don't want to focused.
Is it possible to focus out from that div after triggered. If any other approach is possible, then advice.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$(".use-ajax-comments").blur();
```

Follow [.blur() documentation](http://api.jquery.com/blur/)

Comment: still doesn't work! still focused on the comments div,when page loads,which is at the bottom of my page,jquery auto scrolling to that div when triggered and made focused.

Comment: I want that page loads normally with triggering the div.

Comment: you can set focus on any another form element which is in starting of your form, Or please put whole page html code in your question

Comment: I can't put the whole html, cause am using drupal,which generates HTML internally.